# my .htaccess file rewrite something wrong

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with .htacces file.
Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong here?

I will show you some screenshot:  This image shows my Cpanel my Script files is in home/lulu/public_html/

[image]

And another problem is: When i click my friends picture his/her profile it shows me my profile but url is www.ecoshoptr.com/rajesh

[image]

last proflem is when i click my friends button page said (Not: I have no friends folder )

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $base_url.'friends/'.$session_username; ?>">Friends</a></li>
```

[image]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ecoshoptr.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ecoshoptr.com/$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1

Comment: @Howlin please help me dear. I think that for the full two hours but could not find the problem. Please check my script [Link](www.ecoshoptr.com) than register it is easy. when you are loged in click the friends button then see what is wrong. It said The requested URL /friends/MustafaOeztuerk was not found on this server.

Comment: When you go to `friends/NAME` it will silently get rewritten to `index.php?id=friends/NAME`. It looks to me that it might be a problem of the php code reading that id.

Comment: @Howlin My script working great in my mampserver nothing any problem

Comment: You still did not answer to the question in the first comment here. I mean really answer the question, not write anything roughly matching.

Comment: The problem that you are now having is a php problem. You are querying the wrong information.

Comment: Your first problem was a htacces problem yes, but your current one is not. There is something wrong with the php code and that is another question (which can be asked by clicking on the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button (in the top right hand corner of the page).

Comment: @meda This is my problem

Answer (score 0):

I dont if you left it out but the [L] param prevents it from further rewriting and thus not ending up in your last rules

Maybe you can turn on your RewriteLog if that is available on your apache version

```
RewriteRule foo bar [L]
```

Comment: Actually it might well be wanted that the rewritten url gets further rewrites in this case...

Comment: true, the first condition looks like that every subdomain should be redirected to www.

But now i take a closer look it seems the problem lies within regular expression. There is class present that only accepts certain characters and the slash is not one of them..

so /friends/MustafaOeztuerk never gets forwarded?

Comment: Might be, but this is _wild guessing_, there is little sense in it. It rarely makes sense to post an "answer" as soon as one has an idea what _might_ be an issue. The question is totally unclear, the OP does not really point out what he attempts to do, not even when asked. Sad, but little one can do...

Comment: also true, but now he has two more options to try out. or am i missing certain rules here? Im pretty new to stackoverflow when it comes down to helping people

Comment: @klapvee i have no subdomain dear.

Comment: @klapvee my all files is in /home/lulu/public_html/ here.

Comment: You should write a comment if you just want to add a thought to the discussion. Only post an answer if you are convinced that you actually hit the problem at hand. Otherwise all questions get polluted with numerous "answers" from everyone who has an idea about what might be an issue in a situation. That is not really helpful.

Comment: i will try to keep that in mind arkascha. But in the first comments he said the problem is that " /friends/MustafaOeztuerk" gives a 404. And that is probably caused by the regular expression. but i didnt test so i can never be sure of that right? :)

Comment: @arkascha i edited my question can you check it now ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following two lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```

Your rules would only rewrite urls that has characters `a-z` in lower and upper case, an underscore, a `-` and digits 0-9. The url `friends/Name` wouldn't match that rule because it has a `/` in it. The rule I have will accept that. Also I combined the two rules into the by adding a `?` after the `/` because it will say that it might be there and it might not be there.

Comment: it said now INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: you are perfect link is working now but another problem will come. When i click friends button it shows me only my profile :S

Comment: thanks for this. now it works but another problem will come . When i click the friends button it shows me only my profile. Username: srinivas
Password: 9lessons can you check inside [www.ecoshoptr.com](www.ecoshoptr.com)

Comment: I'm seeing a 404 page?

Comment: yes sir, I've become old because of all the links were directed to the same place. and logout did not work

Comment: dear i am using this script. Script seller told in this page can you checked it http://www.9lessons.info/2010/03/htaccess-file-inside-folder.html

Comment: script seller use subdomain but i am not using subdomain

Comment: If you are clicking on the friends tab and only your profile is showing up, then I think it might be a problem of how you are querying the information. As for why that is failing that would be a new question you need to ask.

Comment: can you help me out teamweaver ?You are too good, please help.